# Tool-set for a craigslist-like app

Tags: ruby, cordova, amazon-web-services, sencha-touch, extjs

Appreciate some guidance - I'm trying to learn how to build HTML5 web-apps with an example:a simple Craigslist-like app that allows people to post as well as view items for sale using Web as well as mobile. Here's the tool-set I have in mind.

GUI: Sencha Touch

Server-side code: Java (should I be using Ruby or Python?)

Database: MySQL

Hosting: AWS

Other: PhoneGap to use camera function for image/video upload

Do you have any comments or suggestions on the above tool-set?

Comment: Use tools you are comfortable with or want to learn.  There is no right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use AWS directly unless you are very familiar with it. Try [heroku](http://heroku.com). You can deploy java, python, ruby or pretty much anything with a simple git push. You don't have to worry about setting up servers and a basic account is free. You will wanting to be using Postgresql rather than MySQL with heroku as that is their standard database.

Ruby Rails can be a bit heavy upfront. Maybe look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) which has a slightly less steep learning curve.

Comment: Thank you. There are couple of reasons I mentioned AWS and RoR. I would like to learn AWS concepts as well to apply on scalable architectures. Is Heroku equally scalable - are there any popular apps using it? Similar question on Sinatra - does it scale well? I guess RoR is not that great in scalability since Twitter replaced their RoR core by Java.

Comment: Heroku is a service layer on top of AWS and can scale front end web servers and background job processors horizontally. It can also scale it's postgres service to suit your needs. If you need to be cool and run a NoSQL db such as couch or redis you can add those in with a click.

Comment: And the heroku front page lists some big names using it.

Comment: I see Asics and Scvngr there...thanks, will definitely check it out.